# Where exactly are the default js files in magento are used?

Tags: javascript, magento

Magento by default includes all the js files.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ccard.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/varien/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
```

I want to remove prototype,scriptaculous libraries and use jquery in place of them. How can i know where these libraries are used and what is the role of the rest of js files. These files are unnecessary included whether you system requires them or not.

Any hints?

Comment: They are used everywhere, all of Magento is based on prototype, because prototype was more mature than jquery at the time of concept.  The checkout almost completely depends on prototype.

Comment: also prototype is not compresses.. does prototype has any problem with minified version

Comment: I haven't seen very many issues with it.  I have seen many tools that minify js, but you should be very careful when doing it.  Magento by default has the ability to cache all js into a single js file which I have seen improvement, but you have to be careful of conflicts when you join the skin_js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know where the JS are used see your or if you are using default then default templates layouts... like the examples you have given. But I would suggest you keep both prototype and add JQuery (As many admin features etc use prototype) for the bits you need and there is a work around for the '$' issue when using the two libraries together [see http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries]

Comment: since admin features uses these libraries can i make this happen to load these files only in admin pages and remove them from site frontend...

Answer (score 1):

There are typically 2 main locations for javascript files...

The ones you mention above are located in `[magento-root]/js`

Inside there are many folders that house the different js files (such as `js/scriptaculous/*.js`).

You template also can contain custom js files..

They are usually located at `skin/frontend/[package]/[template]/js`

Answer (score 1):

You can add/remove JS files (as well as CSS files) via Layouts XML.

Most JS files are loaded via app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/layout/page.xml

```
       <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
```

This layout page.xml is like a default layout that will load for most pages. You may comment desired lines here (within your own theme), or declare your jquery files. Make sure to make you jquery files available in dedicated folders.

However, should you need to make these jquery files available for only one (or some) module(s), you should not load it via page.xml but via the desired module layout, directly. Example: if you need to remove/add a CSS/JS file for the Contact Us page, then you would make your declaration into contacts.xml, otherwise your files would load and/or be removed almost everywhere in your store.

Finally, unless you made a custom theme *full css* whitout any javascript, I see no reason to remove prototype and/or scriptaculous files. With regard to jquery, it could be added easily on top of prototype but make sure to configure it properly to avoid any conflict between both those libraries.